# Update MultiSelectListPreference list programatically

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I want to use a predefined list of elements in the android app settings using a MultiSelectListPreference and a few values already predifined in an xml file.

This is how it looks like

XML-File

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="myTestList">
        <item>Item 1</item>
        <item>Item 2</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And in the preferences.xml I added

```
 <PreferenceCategory app:title="Example Title">
        <MultiSelectListPreference
            android:entries="@array/myTestList"
            android:entryValues="@array/myTestList"
            android:summary="yes / no"
            android:title="Example Title 2" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
```

So far it works and with

```
val myPreference: SharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
var sets: MutableSet<String?> = HashSet()
sets = myPreference.getStringSet("myTestList", HashSet<String>()) as MutableSet<String?>
sets.add("Item 3")
myPreference.edit().putStringSet("myTestList", sets).apply()
System.out.println("New list" + myPreference.getStringSet("myTestList", HashSet<String>()) as MutableSet<String?>)
```

What it does is to take the values from the predefined xml, adds a new element, save it and it works fine when i do the system out.

But now my problem: this new list should now be displayed in the settings of the app and here I fail to understand what i have to do to display it instead of using

```
android:entries="@array/myTestList"
android:entryValues="@array/myTestList"
```

Which ofcause is not working as this just points to the xml which now got updated.

Hope its understandable what i mean - im a beginner and using this forum for the first time.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why can't you just add the third item to the `myTestList` in xml file?

Comment: Its just the beginning. The Idea is to have a predefined set of elements for the beginning and give the user the option to add more elements later if needed.